# ssh hangs if the command is larger than 1374 bytes

Tags: ssh

I'm having trouble executing long commands with ssh. The following works fine:

```
echo 'cd /home/www; echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaassssssssssssssssssssddddddddddddddddffffffffffffffffffffffffggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggghhhhhhhh' \
    | ssh -p '32' www@hostname /bin/bash
```

If I add another char to the command, `ssh` hangs indefinitely. If I first log in and then enter my command interactively, there is no length limit; unfortunately, I need to run the (generated) command from a script, so that doesn't solve the problem.

Versions for both client and server: OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5.

What can be the problem?

Comment: can you `scp` a large file to the same server without hangs?

Comment: Looks like a network issue to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be not SSH problem, but the problem of your network, or rather it [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) settings. Such problem described in detail [here](http://www.snailbook.com/faq/mtu-mismatch.auto.html).